# ImageMagick change an image ratio without cropping?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

```
magick "E:\image.jpg" -extent 1:1.5 "E:\image_x.jpg"
magick "E:\image.jpg" -gravity center -extent 1:1.5 "E:\image_x.jpg"
```

These codes crop the images. How can I change an image ratio without cropping? I need this ratio w:1 / h:1,5 and without cutting.Thanks..

Comment: What size is your image? What size are you hoping it will become?

Comment: Before = 2255x2633   After  =   1862x2633   However, it cutted. I don't need specific sizes. I need this ratio w:1 h:1,5 of course without cutting.

Comment: How can that be correct? 2633/1862 is not 1.5, it is 1.414 ?

Comment: If you do not want to crop, you can pad to that ratio. Or you can force it to distort to that ratio.  What would you like to do?

Comment: Ok, how can I do this ( pad or distort)? For convenience, I just say 1.5 @MarkSetchell.